# Bibtex citation from IEEE is incomplete

Tags: bibtex, ieee-style

I always export bibtex citations directly from the IEEE website. However, I noticed that it is not always complete and sometimes missing few items specially for conferences. What is the best way to automatically generate the bibtex citations?

Here is an example where the full name of the conference and location are missing:

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{6887156,
  author={Jia, Zhensheng and Chien, Hung-Chang and Zhang, Junwen and Dong, Ze and Cai, Yi},
  booktitle={OFC 2014}, 
  title={Performance analysis of pre- and post-compensation for bandwidth-constrained signal in high-spectral-efficiency optical coherent systems}, 
  year={2014},
  volume={},
  number={},
  pages={1-3},
  doi={10.1364/OFC.2014.W3K.3}}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on the meaning of "not always complete and sometimes missing few items". E.g., are entire fields missing in some typeset entries? Which entry types do you employ for "conferences"? Could you edit your query to show some bib entries that are affected by the "not always complete" problem?

Comment: Added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several doi to bibtex covertors, eg google suggested https://www.bibtex.com/c/doi-to-bibtex-converter/ and pasting

`10.1364/OFC.2014.W3K.3`

produced

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{Jia2014-ub,
  title      = "Performance analysis of pre- and post-compensation for
                bandwidth-constrained signal in high-spectral-efficiency
                optical coherent systems",
  booktitle  = "Optical Fiber Communication Conference",
  author     = "Jia, Zhensheng and Chien, Hung-Chang and Zhang, Junwen and
                Dong, Ze and Cai, Yi",
  publisher  = "OSA",
  year       =  2014,
  address    = "Washington, D.C.",
  conference = "Optical Fiber Communication Conference",
  location   = "San Francisco, California"
}
```

so you could just use the DOI and use an alternative DOI lookup such as this if it gives better bibtex entries.

Comment: although actually there is no extra information here other than `OFC 2014` being expanded to `Optical Fiber Communication Conference`